# Lambda Expression with self reference - what is it doing?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have come across code that I need to debug. It is a filter on a collection that appears to reference itself.

```
tempSomeObjects = SomeObjects.SelectMany(fk => (from k1 in Lista
    from k2 in K1.Listb
    from k3 in k2.Listc
    from k4 in k3.Listd
    from k5 in k4.Liste
    where (k4.name1 + k5.name2) == fk
    select new SomeObjects(k4.name1, k5.name2, string.Empty, "ww"))).ToList();
```

I have tried to 'simplify' it as below

```
foreach (var k1 in Lista)
{
    foreach (var k2 in K1.Listb)
    {
        foreach (var k3 in k2.Listc)
        {
            foreach (var k4 in k3.Listd)
            {
                foreach (var k5 in k4.Liste)
                {
                    //This bit doesnt work like original ccode 
                    //as it simply gives me back everything in the liste

                    // The next few lines are what I need help with - as in what you
                    // think is trying to be selected based on the original code
                    tempSomeObject = new SomeObjects(
                        k4.name1, k5.name2, string.Empty, "ww");

                    if ((k4.name1 + k5.name2) ==
                        (tempSomeObject.name1, tempSomeObject))
                    {
                        tempSomeObjects.Add(tempSomeObject);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I am pretty sure I am missing at least 1 step as the filtering from original code isnt being done.
Please advise as to what that `fk` is doing and what the equivalent is in the simplief code.

Thanks

Comment: wheres your iteration of "SomeObjects", which is where fk is coming from

Comment: Please clarify what `SomeObjects` is - looks like some type and collection at the same time (possible, but clarification would be useful). Also make sure to read help on `SelectMany` and comment in your post on what exactly you have problem with converting it to non-LINQ code.

Comment: Where is the "self reference", what is the problem, and why do you think the insane loop nesting is an improvement?

Comment: the "insane loop nesting" is to try and show what the lambda exp is doing

Comment: thanks all. When I say 'self reference', I mean the fact that the variable fk is being used as a reference but also within the expession ... eg SomeList.Select(c => someRandomthing = c). I haven come across that syntax before

Comment: SomeObjects is a List<SomeObject> Alexei. You said its possible for a type to also be a collection, how does that work? My attempt to convert is not working as I dont know how to implement the filter. What I have done simple gives me back everything in the list. If you can explain how the use of fk is working or what I can read, it would help

Comment: Hi Keith, alot of the original code is fairly confidential so I had to change type names and missed one ...you can now see where I'm thinking the iteration coould occur

Comment: `if ((k4.name1 + k5.name2) == (k4.name1, k5.name2, string.Empty, "ww"))` Isn't that invalid syntax?

Comment: Hi Matthew, that whole bit is a mess after the comment as that's where I need help with. I cant figure out what the original code is trying to do and be able to recreate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expanded logic indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of what the Lamba and LINQ expressions are trying to do. You're missing an interator over the (I'm guessing) collection of strings that "SomeObjects" is a wrapper of. The first thing you need to do is utilize your debugger to determine what the actual contents of 'SomeObjects' is. You probably should also look into the contents of lista through liste, again using your debugger.

You hint at some manual obfuscation of your code. Are the lists contained in the lists each actually named subsequently like that? I only ask because I cannot possibly imagine a scenario where you have several nested lists of the same type (looks that way to me), but a different name in each recursive layer. I guess stranger things have happened...

Now for my guess at a breakdown of what's happening, given the information I have available. I'm making several guesses here based on the context, so I could be all wet.

SomeObjects (why would you name the object the same as the class, capitalization included?) looks like a class which inherits IEnumerable or similar, but with a constructor which accepts either 4 strings or perhaps a params array of strings. I say this because its contents are clearly being iterated through and compared as strings.

The nested list objects are a little more complex, but again the name1 and name2 objects appear to be strings, and it appears that each list has a list of its same type or a similar type. so...

For each string in SomeObjects, iterate over the listb of lista, then over the listc of listb, then over the listd of listc, then over the liste of listd. This is to get each name1 value in listd's objects and get each name2 in liste's objects. Those two names are combined, then compared against the string defined by fk in the lambda expression at the top. If there is a match, create a new SomeObjects object, with the four strings defined above, and return a list of each SomeObject object created.

And finally, I will try to correct your syntax in the second example, although I have no way to verify it since I know nothing of the objects you're dealing with...

```
var tempSomeObjects = new List<SomeObjects>();
foreach(var fk in SomeObjects)
{
    foreach(var k1 in lista)
    {
        foreach(var k2 in k1.listb)
        {
            foreach(var k3 in k2.listc)
            {
                foreach(var k4 in k3.listd)
                {
                    foreach(var k5 in k4.liste)
                    {
                        if ((k4.name1 + k5.name2) == fk)
                        {
                            tempSomeObjects.Add(new SomeObjects(k4.name1, k5.name2, string.Empty, "ww"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not see any kind of a self-reference, but I'm sure the code could be quite a bit cleaner. More detail would help tremendously in deciphering what is happening or what should be happening, especially if you would like help cleaning it up or fixing it.

Comment: Thanks much, alll of this helps. Yes of course all the names I have used are over simplified but the logic is the same. I am building essentially a human interface application on top of someonelse's core software so I can only imaging they had some valid reason to same name class and object names ...even if it was just to make the software more complicated than it needs to be. However, now you guys have clarified how fk may have come to be, it helps me dig further

Answer (score 0):

In a C# lambda expression, the syntax `a => doSomethingWith(a)` creates an anonymous function, where the part to the left of the `=>` is the function's parameter list and the part to the right is the function body.

Therefore, in the case of your mystery function:

```
fk =>
    // ...
    where k4.name + k5.name == fk
    // ...
```

The identifier `fk` refers to the currently selected item from `SomeObjects`, not the expression itself. `SelectMany` is a Linq method that enumerates an `IEnumerable` and returns a new flat `IEnumerable` where each element in the new collection is the result of calling the given anonymous function on an element of the original collection.

It appears that `SomeObjects` is a collection of strings, and that for each string, we want to find some elements from another collection that are complementary substrings of this string. For example, if `fk` is `"foobar"`, the corresponding element(s) of the result might be created from `"foo"` and `"bar"` (or `"f"` and `"oobar"`, for that matter).

The exact semantics of this particular function depends on a lot of details we don't know.

Comment: This is of great help Austin - even just from using the right terminologies - Identifier being a parameter in an anonymous function